# How can i add an icon to a submenu in a VS2010 add-in?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, com, ole, vsx

I can add an icon to a menu item by adding an `<icon>` to the `<button>` element in the in the *.vsct file of my Visual Studio Package.

Unfortunately the `<icon>`issn't available available in a `<menu>` element.

**How can i add an icon to a submenu?**

It is possible to do this from code (preferibly C#)?
Maybe via injecting something into the COM / OLE layer?

TortoiseSVN has a icon in the explorer popup menu, have you ever seen a VS plugin that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible using VS menus (not with vsct, C#, etc), and they're not very extensible in this regard.  However, depending on what you're trying to do, (e.g. if you're looking to do this in a context menu within a tool window rather than the VS menu bar), you may be able to use WPF context menus which should give you the control you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure TortoiseSVN explorer context menu and what you are trying to do in Visual Studio extension are same. As I understand, VSCT [Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166515.aspx) element cannot have Icon. Only [Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166194.aspx) element supports icons. You can check this [blog post](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2010/05/23/vs-2010-package-development-chapter-2-commands-menus-and-toolbars.aspx) from DiveDeeper for more information.